# object in prototype is inherited as reference

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype

I want to inherit new object instance using prototype.

Test case:

```
var MyObj = function() {}
MyObj.prototype.objName = {} 
// I want this to be a different object for each instance of MyObj

var o1 = new MyObj (),
    o2 = new MyObj ();

o1.objName['a'] = 1;
o2.objName['a'] = 2;

alert(o1.objName['a']) // 2
alert(o1.objName === o2.objName) // true
```

This means that objects in prototype are not inherited as its copies but instead as its reference.

I know that normally you can do it like this.

```
var MyObj = function() {
    this.objName = {}
}

var o1 = new MyObj(),
    o2 = new MyObj();

alert(o1.objName === o2.objName) // false
```

This works fine, but in my case this is not an option. I really need to define objName outside the MyObj function.

I managed to "solve" the problem with this

```
MyObj.prototype.objName = function() {
    if ( this._objName === undefined ) {
        this._objName = {};
    }
    return this._objName;
}

var o1 = new MyObj(),
    o2 = new MyObj();

o1.objName()['a'] = 1;
o2.objName()['a'] = 2;

alert(o1.objName()['a']) // 1
```

But this is not very pretty and the performance of this code is much worse.

Is there any way to solve this more elegantly ?

Comment: Why do you need to define `objName` outside the constructor?

Comment: I am making a library that allows the user to extend his objects with some functionality and I need to add some objects in his object to support the additional functionality. I don't want to bother the user by forcing him declare these properties himself. I hope I explained myself understandably :)

Comment: Why do you think performance would be *much* worse? Of course, there's an additional function call, but you cannot prevent that if you don't want to use the constructor function.

Comment: According to www.jsperf.com the perfomance was 76% slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This means that objects in prototype are not inherited as its copies but instead as its reference.

Nothing on the prototype is copied - the whole concept of prototypical inheritance is that properties *reference* the shared properties of the prototype object. So if you want a property to be individual for each instance, you have to explicitly assign it to the object and *shadow* the prototype property; just as you're doing it with the `_objName` property in your code.

> But this is not very pretty and the performance of this code is much worse.

If you want it pretty, move it to the constructor (or make the constructor look for something like an `init` method to call if exists, then you can create that init method on the prototype.

To make performance a little better, you can change the getter function to

```
MyObj.prototype.getObj = function() {
    var obj = {};
    this.getObj = function(){ return obj; }; // overwrite itself
    return obj;
};
```

though it still has the function call overhead. For even more elegance, you can use a getter property (not supported in old browsers) that removes itself on the first access:

```
Object.defineProperty(MyObj.prototype, "objName", {
    get: function() {
        var obj = {};
        Object.defineProperty(this, "objName", {
            value: obj,
            writable: true //?
        });
        return obj;
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Now you can omit the function call parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

> This means that objects in prototype are not inherited as its copies but instead as its reference.

Just to be clear. First of all in JavaScript all objects are passed by reference, not by value. Only primitives are passed by value.
Second, you're not actually "copying" or "passing" anything. When you set a `prototype`, you're creating a prototype's chain. It means that in your case:

```
var MyObj = function() {};
MyObj.prototype.objName = {} ;

var o1 = new MyObj ();
var o2 = new MyObj ();
```

Both `o1` and `o2` doesn't have any property called `objName`, and you can simply test it with:

```
console.log(Object.keys(o1)); // []
```

When JS see a code like `o1.objName`, as first thing checks if the object has this property, and if it has, use it. If not, start to looking in the prototype's chain, starting by the prototype of `o1`, that is `MyObj.prototype`: it found the properties `objName`, and returns it. If it didn't find it, then JS will continue to check the prototype of `MyObj.prototype`, and so on. So, here the point: `MyObj.prototype` *it's* an object: and you shared that object between `o1` and `o2`. That's why the instance of `objName` is the same. It's exactly the same logic of having:

```
function objName(obj) {
    return "objName" in obj ? obj.objName : O.objName;
}

var O = { objName: [] };
var foo = {};
var bar = {};

objName(foo).push(0);
objName(bar).push(1);
```

So, you can't put in `prototype` any object that is not meant to be shared across the objects creates using that prototype. I would say that shared states like that is also a bad practice that should be avoided, that's why in general `prototype` shouldn't have such property.
It's still not clear to me why you can't modify the constructor, but the point is: when you create the instance of your object, you have to "setup" it. Usually, calling the constructor, but any function is fine. This is made also when you want to support inheritance, and calling the "super" constructor to initialize your object.

Comment: Thanks, for clearing how prototype works to me. I thought that the the prototype object is actually copied (kinda like class says what properties will the instance have) to all instances. Big fail on my side :)

Comment: you're welcome. :) Still, I have no idea what's your use case, even after read your comment to @Koterpillar. If you add some "real case example" how your code is intended to use, maybe we can address better your issues.

Comment: Actually, not even objects are passed by reference - they are passed by value as every other variable in JS. Only, objects are *reference values* to their property maps. You might share that reference, but you're passing it by value :-)

Comment: With "by reference" we meant the value is not copied. With "by value" means the value is copied. That's the terminology in JS (see, for instance, "arguments" in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Glossary). Sure, you can think about "Object reference" as pointer in C, and under the hood not only the objects can be shared but also different properties from different objects can shares the same descriptor for performance reasons; but that are implementation details of the engine. :)